# MySQL Comando SELECT

Tags: sql, select

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT Especies.nombre AS Nombre,Tipos.nombre AS 'Tipo 1',Tipos.nombre AS 'Tipo 2' 
FROM Especies,Tipos  
WHERE Tipos.idTipos=Especies.Tipo1 OR Especies.Tipo2=Tipos.idTipos 
ORDER BY Especies.nombre;
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo necesitaría modificar la consulta para que el segundo dato de la lista pase a la columna 2.

Cabe aclarar que tanto los campos "Tipo1" y "Tipo2" de la tabla **Especies** son ambas claves foráneas del campo "idTipos" de la tabla **Tipos**.

Agradecería me indiquen que otra herramienta de consulta debo utilizar para poder realizarlo. Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza para poder hacerlo y no lo consigo.

Comment: Hola. No se entiende muy bien tu lógica. Quieres en una columna las especies con `idTipo=1` y en otra las especies con `idTipo=2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me dá la impresión que lo que buscas es mas bien algo como esto:

```
SELECT  e.nombre as Nombre,
        t1.nombre as 'Tipo 1',
        t2.nombre as 'Tipo 2'
        FROM Especies e
        LEFT JOIN Tipos t1
             ON t1.idTipos = e.Tipo1
        LEFT JOIN Tipos t2
             ON t2.idTipos = e.Tipo2
```

Es decir, un `left join` de cada especie entre sus columnas de tipo con su correspondiente valor de nombre en la tabla de `Tipos`. A diferencia de tu consulta, las filas con un solo Tipo, una de las columnas `Tipo1` o `Tipo2` serán `NULL`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Patricio, me ahorraste seguir con dolor de cabeza.

Comment: @NicolásGraciano si la respuesta te sirivio, recuerda aceptarla